# Не могу понять где ошибка в MySQL. Все время вылетает QL Error [1064] [42000]

Tags: mysql, sql

Скрипт не запускается, все время выдает:

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
> the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // create procedure
> sp_friendship_offers(in for_user_id BIGINT UNSI' at line 3

В чем ошибка, плиз, хелп.

Код:

```
  drop procedure if exists sp_friendship_offers;
    
    DELIMITER //

create procedure sp_friendship_offers(in for_user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED)
  begin
    select p2.user_id
    from profiles p1
    join profiles p2 
        on p1.hometown = p2.hometown
    where p1.user_id = for_user_id 
        and p2.user_id <> for_user_id 
    
        union 

    select uc2.user_id
    from users_communities uc1
    join users_communities uc2 
        on uc1.community_id = uc2.community_id
    where uc1.user_id = for_user_id 
        and uc2.user_id <> for_user_id

        union 

    select fr3.target_user_id   
    from friend_requests fr1
        join friend_requests fr2 
            on (fr1.target_user_id = fr2.initiator_user_id 
                or fr1.initiator_user_id = fr2.target_user_id)
        join friend_requests fr3 
            on (fr3.target_user_id = fr2.initiator_user_id 
                or fr3.initiator_user_id = fr2.target_user_id)
    where (fr1.initiator_user_id = for_user_id or fr1.target_user_id = for_user_id)
        and fr2.status = 'approved'
        and fr3.status = 'approved'
        and fr3.target_user_id <> for_user_id 
    
    order by rand()
    limit 5;
  end
  // 
  
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Что должен делать ваш код?

Comment: вы, видимо, отправили этот файл mysql-серверу. а сервер понятия не имеет о команде delimiter. команду эту понимает и интерпретирует mysql-клиент.

Comment: Глеб, этот код должен по определенным критериям совпадения выводить пользователей.

Comment: я работаю через DBeaver

Comment: а без делимитера этого увас оно не работает?

Comment: нет, но, по идее, оно и не должно работать без delimitera

Comment: Попытка использовать команду delimiter с клиентом, который её не поддерживает, приведёт к тому, что эта команда будет отправлена серверу, а тот сообщит о синтаксической ошибке.